# The favicons on stackexchange.com/users/ seem to be stacked on top of one another

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

When I look at e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/1668748/senshin, I see the following under "Top Questions":

[image]

It appears that the MSO sprite is being stacked on top of the sprite for some beta site which I can't identify. I have cleared my cache and hard-refreshed, so this probably isn't a problem on my end.

This appears to be related to the fact that `favicon.css` specifies a `background-image` for `.favicon`.

Comment: Hah. That's my bad. Fixing.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the beta site in question is [academia.se].

Comment: ...and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png says I guessed right. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repeat after me, folks: CSS if fun!

(The fix is rolling out now.)

Comment: CSS if fun! ...

Comment: You sure this is rolling out? It's still happening for me...

Comment: @hichris123 Caching may be at play. I'll take another look tomorrow if it's still happening.

Comment: I can pretty much confirm that this isn't client-side caching... (I can try it on a computer that has never visited SE before to double check).

Comment: @hichris123 I can confirm the issue on the prod tier still, but not on dev (running the same code). I can't dig further into it right now, though, but at least it's not dire. Hence, tomorrow.

Comment: Still, I can see the issue.

Comment: Still an issue: [Top Network Sites favicons are bugged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226297)

Comment: Derp. I see what the issue is. Working on a fix.

Comment: @AnnaLear Rolling out in the next build?

Comment: @hichris123 Should be fixed for real now.