# Top Network Sites favicons are bugged

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, favicon

on [this page](https://stackexchange.com/questions) looking myself it seems to be a missing `favicon-*` class

likely the same css issue as [The favicons on stackexchange.com/users/ seem to be stacked on top of one another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226231/the-favicons-on-stackexchange-com-users-seem-to-be-stacked-on-top-of-one-anothe)

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this. @IlmariKaronen Anna said it's fixed on dev but for some reason the fix isn't working (yet) on production.

Comment: Ah, yes, I can repro this now. I was looking in the wrong place, sorry. [Here's a link to a page where you can see this](http://stackexchange.com/questions); look in the sidebar.

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate; Anna states in the comments she'd look into the issue today (and she's in US, so 'today' starts later for her).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been caused by the deployment of the new top bar to http://stackexchange.com.  The problem is that both the topbar style sheet and the stackexchange.com style sheet are using the `favicon` class to display site icons, but they're using it in completely different ways.  (The top bar is using CSS sprites, while the sidebar is using plain old `<img>` tags.)

A quick CSS workaround for this bug would be to add the rule:

```css
img.favicon { background: none }
```

However, a better fix would be to change the `.favicon` selector in the top bar style sheet to e.g. `.topbar .favicon`, thereby ensuring that it won't match elements outside the top bar.  Presumably, this is something like what [Anna's fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226233) will do, once it's been rolled out properly.